# Access Database Handler Inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent, kotlin

I am trying to access database Handler inside a fragment but its throwing me does not have companion object error. I tried database handler query and its working fine. Any help is appreciated.

**Language Used**

```
Kotlin
```

**Code**

```
class OneFragment : Fragment() {

     companion object
{
//Error in the below context
    var db=TestDatabaseHandler(Context)
}

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    {
    
    var a=db.readData()
    
    }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `context` inside `companion object {}`. Instead change `db` to be a field to class `OneFragment` like this

```
class OneFragment : Fragment() {

    val db by lazy { TestDatabaseHandler(context!!) }

    override fun onCreateView(...)
        var a = db.readData()
    }
}
```

Reference - [Property delegation in Kotlin](https://antonioleiva.com/property-delegation-kotlin/)  by Antonio Leiva

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that one already but getting NullPointerException.val db=TestDatabaseHandler(this!!.context!!)

Comment: Actually in your `TestDatabaseHandler` class you should accept a nullable context and do a null check wherever you use it

Comment: This is my database handle class TestDatabaseHandler(var context: Context) :
        SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION)

    {
 }

Comment: There is a beautiful way in Kotlin to address this issue called lazy delegation. I have updated the answer to work properly.